# Alternate CD install missing wallpapers?

Tags: installation, desktop-background, alternate

I've set up several 12.04 desktop machine using the regular installer.  However, on another machine I needed to set up software RAID so I used the alternate installer.

I noticed however, that the 12.04 wallpapers are not present on this new machine...just the ones from 11.10.  Two questions:

1) Is this a bug?
2) How to get the 12.04 wallpapers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install it through

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-precise
```

[image: Install via the software center]

For offline downloading through launchpad refer this

[“ubuntu-wallpapers” source package in Precise](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/)

Or the site `webupd8.org` here

[Ubuntu 12.04 Wallpapers Updated (Community, Default Wallpaper)](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/ubuntu-1204-wallpapers-updated.html)

Through the [Cd image Contents list it is there](http://nl.releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.list). Search for wallpapers there, you will find it.